# concatenate few .xml files in one bigger .xml document

Tags: powershell, xml

Exist the possibility to concatenate more .xml files in just one .xml document using powershell?
For example I have 14 .xml file which have the same format (columns/name of columns) and I want in concatenate all these .xml files in one bigger .xml file which will be imported in power bi template in order to create a general report?

Comment: [Merge multiple XML files into one using PowerShell 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972264/)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use the PS code from example but it doesn't work for me:

> $finalXml = "C:xmlfiles" foreach ($file in $files) {
> [xml]$xml = Get-Content $file
> $finalXml += $xml.InnerXml } $finalXml += $xml.root.InnerXml ([xml]$finalXml).Save("$pwd\final.xml")

I get this error :
Cannot convert value "C:xmlfiles" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument".
Error: "The specified node cannot be inserted as the valid child of this node,
because the specified node is the wrong type."
At line:7 char:1

- ([xml]$finalXml).Save("$pwd\final.xml")
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastToXmlDocument
  ```